# Which phrase is the most correct/idiomatic in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

> Since I am not yet fully scheduled, **at the moment** I cannot say for
>   sure which period is suitable for me. Is it OK if I let you know about
>   this in 3 weeks once I am fully scheduled?

At the moment? at this moment? at this time? at the present time? ... ?

Comment: Personally, I would remove the phrase altogether. To me, it sounds more natural to simply say *since I am not yet fully scheduled, I cannot say . . .* There is no reason to add the extra phrasing. **Unless** you move the comma from before the time phrase to after it. But nobody can objectively answer *Which phrase is the most correct?*

Answer (score 3):

"right now" is probably more common, especially in speech, than any of "at the moment",  "at this moment", "at this time", or "at the present time".

As a matter of style, I would tend to favor "at the moment", but it would depend on context and the style of speech/writing that I was aiming for. Any of these is grammatical.